# No Hashset<T, G> for .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm getting back into using MonoTouch, and I tried using

```
HashSet<int, List<MyClass>>
```

I have a using for `System.Collections.Generic`, however I'm getting an error on the `HashSet` declaration, specifically I'm getting

> The type or namespace name 'HashSet`2'
>   could not be found.  Are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?

My code is having no issues with `List`, but adding in the `HashSet` I get this issue. Anyone have an idea as to the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HashSet<>` is a collection class supporting individual items, hence it only has one generic type parameter. The dual parameter mapping is a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: Thanks, the error message really through me off and I didn't realize it was for a single use generic. Much appreciated.